# Helping AppActivate find my program

Tags: vba

I built a VBA script that activates my companies enterprise database software and takes a screenshot of error messages to compile them and send them to our IT department when they pop up.

The problem is that it has about a 30 percent chance of not finding the database program.

I am using AppActivate, and having it reiterate the command with different variations on the name. (I borrowed this chunk of code from elsewhere when my AppActivate was missing 60-70% of the time.)

"PROGname v2 - [title of menu user is on]" is the menu-bar name for the program. Is there something I can be doing to grab it every time?

```
Sub ActivateWin()
'Activates The Program by window name
    On Error Resume Next          'we ignore all errors until we reach last AppActivate
    AppActivate ("PROG")
    If Err.Number = 5 Then Err = 0:  AppActivate ("PROGname v2")
    If Err.Number = 5 Then Err = 0:  AppActivate ("PRO")
    If Err.Number = 5 Then Err = 0:  AppActivate ("P")
    If Err.Number = 5 Then Err = 0:  AppActivate ("prog")
    If Err.Number = 5 Then Err = 0:  MsgBox "PROGname not found. Please go yell at MYNAME!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try another way with the [`FindWindow`](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/10/25/findwindow/) command (some other info [here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml)).

In order to find which class refer to your progam, you can use this addin: http://www.xcelfiles.com/API_06.html or get inspired by the code and customize it to your needs.